# Windows 8 Backup/Restore application

Tags: c#, c++, windows, windows-8.1, windows-api-code-pack

I am new in Windows Software (not app) development. Now I want to build a software having options like this-

1. This position is to create a piece of software which monitors all changes a user makes to a public windows 8 machine (registry+files). When the user is done, store all registry changes and files in a single compressed file.
2. Decompress+Expand the single file and copy+replace all files to the PC with those from the file. Then copy and merge/replace the registry in favor of the values in the file. (All of this must happen without a reboot).

I don't have a idea from where will I start.
Can anyone please help me so that I can have a idea to start this job?

Is there any documentation I need to read?
Or any example?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Is it possible to make change and take effect in windows 8 registry without a reboot?

Comment: Yes, you will - if you have access - be able to modify all of the registry without rebooting. However that does not help you if not ALL of the running applications + OS is reading the new values immediately. And I don't think they all do. So a reboot will be required for all settings to come into effect. Or restart of all the processes running. Another issue is if you write new values and the applications overwrite your changes again. Then you've lost your changes.

Comment: thanks. Can you please help me about my main question?

Where can I start?

Comment: Instead of monitoring files the user changes, just create a snapshot of the disk as you want it to be, and when necessary restore the disk to that state. Monitoring changes adds a lot of work for little return in this case.

Answer (score 0):

> This position is to create a piece of software which monitors all changes a user makes to a public windows 8 machine (registry+files). When the user is done, store all registry changes and files in a single compressed file.

You can look into procmon.exe from sysinternals, it monitors lots of things and outputs it to log window. What you are afer is I suppose program that works like procmon. This program must run with admin privilidges.

You program I suppose would have to use: [RegNotifyChangeKeyValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724892(v=vs.85).aspx) and [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) - those are just a hints to help googling. So using those APIs, you would have to save changed information.

Your second question is unclear to me, I dont thing you can replace registry at all.